# Customizing Python 3 syntax

Tags: python, customization

For teaching purposes I must use french keywords and some special syntax in source code
For example, I am asked to use repeat while loops with french keywords. In Python that would give

```
"répéter":
....
....
...."jusqu'à" condition
```

The quotes are here just to indicate the keywords
How would I start to make such lines of code run by an interpreter and execute a repeat while loop
Thanks